# Sort onClick function not working in the header it says because of Invalid hook call but I can't quite pinpoint where the mistake is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think this has something to do with my routing ? because when I click on another route and then click back into the table component the sorting function does work.

This is the error that I am recieving

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
> Dismiss
> The error was thrown 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
> at Object.throwInvalidHookError (webpack://earthquake-zen-garden/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:14906:13)
> at useState (webpack://earthquake-zen-garden/./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js?:1508:21)
> at Table (webpack://earthquake-zen-garden/./src/components/Table/Table.js?:16:88)
> at H (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:13603:5)
> at exports.inspectHooksOfFiber (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:13671:12)
> at inspectElementRaw (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:8426:65)
> at Object.inspectElement (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:8709:38)
> at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:10542:56
> at Bridge.emit (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:4225:18)
> at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js:4868:14
> The error occurred at InspectedElementContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:39022:3)
> at Suspense
> at ErrorBoundary_ErrorBoundary (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37375:5)
> at div
> at InspectedElementErrorBoundaryWrapper (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37864:3)
> at NativeStyleContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:40513:3)
> at div
> at div
> at OwnersListContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:33354:3)
> at SettingsModalContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:35975:3)
> at Components_Components (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:42520:52)
> at ErrorBoundary_ErrorBoundary (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37375:5)
> at div
> at div
> at ThemeProvider (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37518:3)
> at PortaledContent (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37548:5)
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at ThemeProvider (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37518:3)
> at TimelineContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:42700:3)
> at ProfilerContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:42146:3)
> at TreeContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:30256:3)
> at SettingsContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:30878:3)
> at ModalDialogContextController (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:37927:3)
> at DevTools_DevTools (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:53807:3)

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "../src/App/App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';
import Details from './components/Details/Details';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import data from './data.json';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const route = (
    <React.StrictMode>
         <Router basename="/">
        <div className="App">
            <Header 
                logo={data.site.logoImage} 
                title={data.site.title} 
                firstName={data.profile.firstName} 
                />
        </div>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="profile" element={<Profile profile={data.profile}/>} />
            <Route path="/details/:id"  element={<Details />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
   
)

ReactDOM.render(route, rootElement);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';

const App = () => {
    
    return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
            <h2>USGS All Earthquakes, Past Hour</h2>
            <Table />
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default App
```

Table.js

```
import '../../App/App.scss';
import TableData from './TableData';
import data from '../../data.json';


const Table = () => {
    const [sortedField, setSortedField] = useState();
    const [sortAscending, setSortAscending] = useState();
    const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState(data.data.features)

    if (sortedField === undefined) {
      sortField("place")
    }

    function sortField(name) {
      setSortAscending(!sortAscending)
      sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.properties[name] < b.properties[name]) {
          return sortAscending ? 1 : -1
        }
        if (a.properties[name] > b.properties[name]) {
          return sortAscending ? -1 : 1
        }
        return 0
      })
      setSortedField(name)
      setSortedData(sortedData)
    }
  
    function sortIndicator(fieldName) {
      if (sortedField === fieldName) {
        if (sortAscending) {
          return "asc"
        }
        return "desc"
      }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <table className="container" >
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                      <th onClick={() => sortField('place') } className={sortIndicator('place')}>Title</th>
                      <th onClick={() => sortField('mag')} className={sortIndicator('mag')}>Magnitude</th>
                      <th onClick={() => sortField('time')} className={sortIndicator('time')}>Time</th>
                </tr>
                <TableData tableData={sortedData}/>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default Table
```